# How to print error when input is not int

Tags: java

so far i've got this, im trying to use command lines in java. And I want to print an error when the input isn't an int.

```
 private static void add(String[] args) {
  if (args.length == 1) {
    System.out.print("Error: Argument count mismatch");
  }
  int num = 0;
  for (int i = 1;i < args.length;i++) {
    if (isInteger(args[i]) == false) {
      System.out.print("Error: Argument type mismatch");
    }
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    num += a;
  }
  System.out.println(num);
}
```

the 2nd if statement is the part where I want to print an error if the input isn't int, I have a isInteger method. But my program crashes instead or printing the error.

edit: this is my isInteger method

```
 public static boolean isInteger(String s) {
  try { 
    Integer.parseInt(s); 
  } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

so there shouldn't be a problem here.

edit2: here is the error that I have gotten

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at MyCLIParser.add(MyCLIParser.java:46)
    at MyCLIParser.main(MyCLIParser.java:10)
```

Comment: What does your isInteger() look like? What is the error you are getting in the log?

Comment: As @ChrisS said, provide the stack trace of your error, and also try to include your isInteger method

Comment: added my isInteger method in there. it just crashes, will put up error code later

Comment: im sorry, here's the error i got java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
 at MyCLIParser.add(MyCLIParser.java:46)
 at MyCLIParser.main(MyCLIParser.java:10)

Comment: @Schuld please add it to your question, so that your question will be more clear, and later people may benefit from it ;)

Comment: @Tarik just done that :), any idea why it crashes?

Comment: @Schuld I added my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal, lets say you have args[i] equal to "someString", then when you call you `isInteger()` function that will return false. Then, when you said `isInteger(args[i]) == false`
that mean `false == false` which is `true`. and the `System.out.print("Error: Argument type mismatch");` will execute properly.

After that, when you call  `int a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);` without catching the `NumberFormatException` it's normal to that your application crash with that exception error.

To handle that, you can just add an else block like suggested in Khanna111's answer, like that:

```
 private static void add(String[] args) {
  if (args.length == 1) {
    System.out.print("Error: Argument count mismatch");
  }
  int num = 0;
  for (int i = 1;i < args.length;i++) {
    if (isInteger(args[i]) == false) {
      System.out.print("Error: Argument type mismatch");
    }
    else {
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    num += a;
    }
  }
  System.out.println(num);
}
```

Or you can use a `continue`, which allows the execution to jump to the next element in the for loop and continues on (updated, Thanks to Tom's comment):

```
 private static void add(String[] args) {
  if (args.length == 1) {
    System.out.print("Error: Argument count mismatch");
  }
  int num = 0;
  for (int i = 1;i < args.length;i++) {
    if (isInteger(args[i]) == false) {
      System.out.print("Error: Argument type mismatch");
      continue;
    }
    int a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
    num += a;
  }
  System.out.println(num);
}
```

Comment: @Tom yes I was out of my mind as I'am travelling now, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. The issue can be read from the stack trace. And this is what you have.

```
if (isInteger(args[i]) == false) {
      System.out.print("Error: Argument type mismatch");
    }
int a = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
```

Note that there is no "`else`" after the "`if`" so the value of "`a`" is attempted to be calculated again even though the args[i] is not an Integer.

I hope you can figure how to resolve this with this hint.